# "They also need the Poland international striker to help sell shirts and add appeal for potential future sponsorship deals." -- why "Poland"?

Tags: adjectives, attributive-nouns

"... Robert Lewandowski (238 goals in eight Bundesliga seasons) to replace Messi's goals, they also need the Poland international striker to help sell shirts and add appeal for potential future sponsorship deals."

The options seem to be "Polish" or "Poland's". Is it a matter of style? I can't imagine seeing something like: "America the best scoring player" -- and my search on the web seems to prove that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, *Poland* is a metonymy referring to the national team, the Poland national football team. *Poland* is also used attributively to modify the noun phrase "international striker". One might even call this grammar concept an attributive metonymy.

This metonymic usage of country names is quite common in sports context. Here are some other examples:

> USA striker Ricardo Pepi just completed a $20m move to Augsburg where he is expected to be a first-team player in the Bundesliga. - *[theguardian.com](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2022/jan/11/usmnt-striker-qatar-world-cup)*

> Atletico Madrid said Alvaro Morata suffered a swollen ankle in Saturday's 3-2 LaLiga defeat at Cadiz, leaving the Spain striker just three weeks to recover before the World Cup in Qatar. - *[dailymail.co.uk](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-11370705/Spain-sweating-Alvaro-Morata-striker-suffers-swollen-ankle-Atletico-Madrid-defeat.html)*

Comment: Yes, a Poland striker plays for the Polish national team, a Polish striker is Polish but might play for any team.